# Using jaxws causes Provider weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl not found

Tags: web-services, web-applications, soap, weblogic, jax-ws

We have created a websevice client using the jaxws-maven-plugin and validated that the WAR file works in our test environment.  However, upon moving the same WAR file to production it now produces this error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create message factory for SOAP:
Provider weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl not found
       at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:116)
```

Has anyone seen this and how was it resolved?

NOTE:  We are deploying to a Glassfish server in both the TEST and PRODUCTION environments.

Answer (score 1):

hmm seems like a simple cp setup issue - can you check/post the classpath on both of these environments? also check to see what is set for the javax.xml.soap.MessageFactor parameter in GF

Comment: `weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl` is found in  webserviceclient.jar version 10.3.  I will try including that in the war file along with the wlt3thinclient.

Comment: I added the jar file nd now I am getting a new error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534365/this-class-does-not-support-saaj-1-3