# This class does not support SAAJ 1.3

Tags: glassfish, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x, liferay-6, java-6

In trying to call a webservice from a portlet from Glassfish to a webservice hosted remotely on weblogic we are getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class does not support SAAJ 1.3
    at   weblogic.webservice.core.soap.SOAPHeaderImpl.addHeaderElement(SOAPHeaderImpl.java:178)
```

I added the webservicesclient.jar from WebLogic to the portlet WAR file.

How is the best way to handle this problem?

EDIT:  Adding webservicesclient.jar was the wrong thing to do.  I removed the jar file and that fixed the problem.  The underlying problem was also fixed with a restart.

Comment: I wonder if this is helpful or just further down the rabbit hole: http://blog.xebia.com/2009/07/14/jax-ws-cxf-and-saaj-on-oracle-weblogic-103/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question. See edit in the question:

EDIT: Adding webservicesclient.jar was the wrong thing to do. I removed the jar file and that fixed the problem. The underlying problem was also fixed with a restart.